# Series containing irrational numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

> How can I find if the series $$\sum a_k =\sum (k-\sqrt{k^2+4k+3})$$ is convergent or divergent?

Let $a_{k}=k-\sqrt{k^2+4k+3}$.

Then $$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\bigg(k-\sqrt{k^2+4k+3}\bigg)\cdot \frac{\bigg(k+\sqrt{k^2+4k+3}\bigg)}{k+\sqrt{k^2+4k+3}}.$$

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{-4k-3}{k+\sqrt{k^2+4k+3}}=-4(\neq 0).$$

So the series $\sum a_{k}$ is divergent.

Is my process correct? If not, how do I solve it? Help me please

Comment: So you took the limit and got a finite value. What do you think is the answer?

Comment: Getting finite value. Means its $k$ th terms goes to finit value $-4$. So it means it is converge. And $\sum a_{k}$ Diverge.

Comment: If you get finite value for the limit of the sequence, does it converge or diverge?

Comment: The sequence $a_{k}$ is Converge while $\sum a_{k}$ is Diverge. Is i am Right.

Comment: The sum is a different story entirely, and your limit calculation is wrong, it should be -2 and not -4.